# Usage of "ratio to" when talking about proportions

Tags: prepositions, phrases, licensing

In my application, the fonts are automatically resized to stay proportional with the window. I am trying to describe it with this sentence:

> Font sizes are dynamically calculated in order to maintain a given
>   ratio to the size of the window

Is that correct? Especially the part "ratio to", I am not sure about that at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "with".

> Font sizes are dynamically calculated in order to maintain a given
>   ratio **with** the size of the window.

Sample usage of "with" from ***Professional Paper -United States Geological Survey***

> Consequently the more femic minerals present, the less salic and
>   smaller the alkalies necessary to maintain a given ratio with
>   diminished salic lime.

Normally, when you use "to" with ratios, it is used to denote division of two quantities(simply put). Like:

> Qty3 is defined as the ratio of Qty1 **to** Qty2

Answer (score 0):

You can talk about *the ratio of A to B*, for example

> The ratio of eggs to sugar is too high in this cake batter!

However, the sentence you gave seems grammatically incorrect to me — I think the *ratio* __ *to* construct requires an 'of' in between (i.e. *ratio of __ to __*). In this case,

> Font sizes are dynamically calculated in order to maintain a given ratio **with** the size of the window.

might be better.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to combine two sentences from the original post:

> Font sizes are dynamically calculated in order to stay proportional to the size of the window.

Optionally, you could replace "stay" with "be" or "remain".

Optionally, you could delete "in order".

Answer (score -2):

I think I would say "maintain a given ratio between the size of the windows".

Given the comments below and revisiting the thread, I now think that what the question initially had is actually correct.

"Font sizes are dynamically calculated in order to maintain a given ratio to the size of the window"

meaning a given ratio of the font size to the size of the window.

Comment: "between… windows" implies that there are two (or more) windows whose sizes are being compared.  But in this example, the fonts are not windows, so there is only one window.

Comment: That's true, you are right I was actually hesitant in saying "the sizes of the window" (can we say sizes?). But regardless, I don't think "with" or "according" are correct.